# Kubernetes create deployment unexpected SchemaError

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-deployment

I'm following that tutorial (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-minikube)
I want to create Kubernetes deployment in yaml file (simple-crud-dpl.yaml):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simple-crud
spec:
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: simple-crud
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: simple-crud
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: simple-crud
          image: simple-crud:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

but when I run `kubectl create -f simple-crud-dpl.yaml` i got:
`error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta2.MetricTarget): invalid object doesn't have additional properties`

I'm using the newest version of kubectl:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.0", GitCommit:"641856db18352033a0d96dbc99153fa3b27298e5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T15:45:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I'm also using minikube locally as it's described in tutorial. Everything is working till deployment and service. I'm not able to do it.

Comment: I'd usually expect to see a line `apiVersion: v1`; does adding that help?

Comment: Result is still the same for others apiVersion

Comment: have you tried linting the yaml? Sometimes that helps resolve some subtle formatting errors.

Comment: I just setup minikube on mac and am running into a similar issue in another tutorial that uses a remote file. 

My error is slightly different: 
`kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-initializer-tutorial/master/deployments/helloworld.yaml
error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.core.v1.DaemonEndpoint): invalid object doesn't have additional properties`

I'm guessing something is messed up with our kubectl setup somewhere

Answer (score 153, accepted):

After installing kubectl with brew you should run:

1. `rm /usr/local/bin/kubectl`
2. `brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli`

And also optionally:

`brew link --overwrite --dry-run kubernetes-cli`.

Comment: can you explain what this is doing please?

Comment: Its worked for me also Do you know the reason behind of this?

Comment: what's the reason for re-linking?

Answer (score 33):

I second @rennekon's answer. I found that I had docker running on my machine which also installs `kubectl`. That installation of kubectl causes this issue to show.

I took the following steps:

- uninstalled it using `brew uninstall kubectl`
- reinstalled it using `brew install kubectl`
- (due to symlink creation failure) I forced brew to create symlinks using `brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli`

I was then able to run my `kubectl apply` commands successfully.

Comment: same, but it was `gcloud` tools which had installed their own, out-of-date relative to the cluster i was targeting, kubectl

Answer (score 31):

I too had the same problem. In my Mac system **kubectl** is running from docker which is preinstalled when I install Docker. You can check this by using below command

```
ls -l $(which kubectl)
```

which returns as

> /usr/local/bin/kubectl ->
>   /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectlcode.

Now we have to overwrite the symlink with kubectl which is installed using brew

```
rm /usr/local/bin/kubectl

brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli
```

(optinal)

```
brew unlink kubernetes-cli && brew link kubernetes-cli
```

To Verify

```
ls -l $(which kubectl)
```

Answer (score 26):

I encountered the same issue on minikube/ Windows 10 after installing Docker.
It was caused by the version mismatch of kubectl that was mentioned a couple of times already in this thread. Docker installs version 1.10 of kubectl. 
You have a couple of options:

1) Make sure the path to your k8s bin is above the ones in docker 
2) Replace the kubectl in 'c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin' with the correct one

Comment: Fixed it for me, I just ran `where kubectl` at the command line to verify that was the version being used by default then `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe` to get the latest one.

Answer (score 12):

Your client version is too old. In my env this version comes with Docker. I have to download new client from https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe and now works fine:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.0", GitCommit:"641856db18352033a0d96dbc99153fa3b27298e5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T15:53:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.0", GitCommit:"641856db18352033a0d96dbc99153fa3b27298e5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T15:45:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Same for me, just replaced the exe and now all is fine

Comment: Seems more relevant than the accepted answer. It answers both "what" and "why".

Answer (score 7):

You can use "--validate=false" in your command. For example:

```
kubectl create -f simple-crud-dpl.yaml --validate=false
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!!!

Also work with:
`kubectl apply -f filename.yaml --validate=false`

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong kubectl version.

Kubectl is compatible 1 version up and down as described [in the official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin)

The error is confusing but it simply means that your version 1.10 isn't sending all the required parameters to the 1.14 api.

Answer (score 2):

I am on Windows 10 with Docker Client and Minikube both installed. I was getting the error below;

> error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.core.v1.Node): invalid object doesn't have additional properties

I resolved it by **updating the version of kubectl.exe to that being used by minikube**. Here are the steps:

Note: Minikube tends to use the latest version of Kubernetes so it will be advisable to grab the latest kubectl.

1. [Download the matching version of kubectl.exe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows).
2. Navigate to your Docker path where your kubectl is located e.g. 
   `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`
3. Place your downloaded kubectl.exe there. If it asks you replace it, please do.
4. Now type `refreshenv` in Powershell.
5. Check the new version if it's what you have placed there; `kubectl version`.

Now you are good, retry whatever tasks you was doing.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting below error while running `kubectl explain pod` on windows 10

```
error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.core.v1.NodeCondition): invalid object doesn't have additional properties
```

I had both Minikube and Docker Desktop installed. Reason for this error, as mentioned in earlier answers as well, was mismatch between server (major 1 minor 15) and client version (major 1 minor 10). Client version was coming from Docker Desktop.
To fix I upgraded kubectl client version to v1.15.1 as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-windows)

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.1/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

Mac user !!! This is for those who installed docker desktop first. The error will show up when you use the apply command. The error comes for a version miss match as some people said here. I did not install kubectl using homebrew. Rather kubectl auto get install when you install docker desktop for mac.

To fix this what I have done is bellow:
Remove the kubectl executable file

```
rm /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Download kubectl:
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl

Change the permission:

```
chmod +x ./kubectl
```

Move the executable file :

```
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

That is it folks!
Just to show it worked here is the output:

```
kubectl apply -f ./deployment.yaml
deployment.apps/tomcat-deployment created
```

Make sure the yml file is correct. I downloaded a valid file from here to test :
https://github.com/LevelUpEducation/kubernetes-demo/tree/master/Introduction%20to%20Kubernetes/Your%20First%20k8s%20App

Answer (score 1):

Was running into the same issue after installing kubectl on my Mac today. Uninstalling kubectl [via `brew uninstall kubectl`] and reinstalling [`brew install kubectl`] resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin),

> You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster.

kubectl v1.10 client apparently makes requests to kubectl v1.14 server without some newly (in 4 minor versions) required parameters.

For `brew` users, reinstall `kubernetes-cli`. It's worth checking what installed the incompatible version. For `brew` users, check the command symlink `ls -l $(which kubectl)`.

Answer (score 1):

For me Docker installation was the problem. As Docker now comes with Kubernetes support, it installs kubectl along with its own installation. I had downloaded kubectl and minikube without knowing it, then my minikube was being used by Docker's kubectl installation.

Make sure that it is not also happening with you.

A second cause would be a deprecated apiVersion in your .yaml files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with error

> error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.storage.v1beta1.CSIDriverList): invalid object doesn't have additional properties

My issue was that my mac was using google's kubectl that was installed with the gcp tools. My path looks there first before going into /usr/local/bin/

Once I run kubectl from /usr/local/bin my problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, kubectl is always using google's kubectl by gcloud tool, or there was most probably a conflict between Homebrew installed and Gcloud Installed kubectl. I uninstalled Homebrew kubectl and upgrade gcloud tool to the latest, which eventually upgrades the kubectl also in the process. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with `imagePullPolicy`, unless you don't have the image locally. The error is about `autoscaling`, which means it's not able to create replicas of the container.

Can you set `replicas: 1` and give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10.0, uninstalling Docker helped me get away this problem. Doing with kubectl and minikube.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered but I though I should post my response since the responses above were helpful but it took me a while to relate it to Azure Dev Ops.

I was getting this error when I was trying to deploy an app to a AKS cluster from Azure Devops. As mentioned above, one of the issues this error could appear is because of version mismatch which was the cause in my case. I fixed it by updating my AKS version into the kubectl advanced configuration section as shown in the figure below

[image: Azure Dev Ops screenshot]